# Display just one number in Vega/Kibana

Tags: kibana, vega

I'm trying to create a query/display that just shows a single number. I've had to do it in vega because the query involves a number of queries, then transforms involving timedeltas to merge the data together.

In my browser developer tools I can see that the data is coming through.

[image: dataset]

All I'm after here is `days` here is my marks section in vega:

```
 "marks": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": { "data": "results" },
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "text": "days",
          "x": {"value": 10},
          "y": {"value": 10},
          "fill": {"value": "red"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1},
          "fontSize": {"value": 100}
        },
          "update": {
          "text": "days",
          "x": {"value": 10},
          "y": {"value": 10},
          "fill": {"value": "red"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1},
          "fontSize": {"value": 100}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I have also tried `{ "field": "days" }` instead of `"days"` along with a good few attempts to change the x,y and fills etc.

I get no errors in the browser and the visualization is just blank.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I'm just facing the same situation right now.

I've managed to put up a minimal working example using Vega-Lite; not sure it is exactly as it is supposed to be, but at least it is working. You can [check it out here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoDQCYAHAF8AupaVxZUNspqyyaUJjgAPTB5AAZjRwgspoIChKmACeOHDhAI4MSLKYdGo0pCCWdiDIAE4A1v4xceFevoqBNIKC4flwYUoBcpgAyjQAXvGoAIwADP3NNYIA8jhIUHTRaL1K3rNDIDN9-blOskHumiDEwQDu-hCY+WyFPSAnKRATDanZOUA).

The code is the following:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": 28}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "text": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  },
  "mark": {
    "type": "text",
    "fill": "red",
    "fontSize": 100,
    "fillOpacity": 1,
    "x": 10,
    "y": 10
  },
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "stroke": "transparent"
    }
  }
}
```

A couple of remarks on the code:

1. I'm using your example's `fill`, `fontSize`, `fillOpacity`, `x` and `y` options; they could be different or even not be there.
2. When displaying just text, the "container" of the visualization can be seen as a small box surrounding the text in a light gray by default. The `"stroke": "transparent"` `config` option is what gets rid of this box.

I'm pretty new to Vega (just started some minutes ago), so my apologies in advance for any possible conceptual errors.

---

## Edit

Looking pretty good in Kibana so far :)

[image: Kibana]